# calling a smart contract function with web3.js

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

Trying to figure out how to get return data from web3 smart contract call. So far I have the ABI and contract address creating the contract here is the code:

```
  const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

  //  Initialize the contract instance

  const kittyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      KittyCoreABI, // import the contracts's ABI and use it here
      CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  );
```

the ABI has a function called getKitty which is:

```
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_id",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getKitty",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "isGestating",
            "type": "bool"
        },
        {
            "name": "isReady",
            "type": "bool"
        },
        {
            "name": "cooldownIndex",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "nextActionAt",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "siringWithId",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "birthTime",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "matronId",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "sireId",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "generation",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "genes",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
```

I am trying to call it and just console log the output for now like:

```
console.log(kittyContract.methods.getKitty(887674))
```

just to see what it returns but im getting an object like:

```
    {call: ƒ, send: ƒ, encodeABI: ƒ, estimateGas: ƒ, arguments: Array(1), …}
arguments
:
[887674]
call
:
ƒ ()
encodeABI
:
ƒ ()
estimateGas
:
ƒ ()
send
:
ƒ ()
_ethAccounts
:
Accounts {_requestManager: RequestManager, givenProvider: MetamaskInpageProvider, providers: {…}, _provider: MetamaskInpageProvider, …}
_method
:
{constant: true, inputs: Array(1), name: "getKitty", outputs: Array(10), payable: false, …}
_parent
:
Contract {_requestManager: RequestManager, givenProvider: MetamaskInpageProvider, providers: {…}, _provider: MetamaskInpageProvider, …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using web3.js 1.0-beta.

You need something like this:

```
console.log(await kittyContract.methods.getKitty(887674).send());
```

or (if not using async/await):

```
kittyContract.methods.getKitty(887674).send().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Depending on your setup, you may need to pass a from address and/or other parameters, e.g.:

```
kittyContract.methods.getKitty(887674).send({ from: ..., ... }).then(...);
```

Comment: yep i didn't realize that it returns a promise. I actually ended up using .call() and it works fine. Now I need to figure out how to convert a uint256 number to date.

Comment: Sorry, yes, for a view function, `call` is what you want (not `send`).

Answer (score 0):

you need to have call() function also at the end, and also you can use callback function.

```
kittyContract.methods.getKitty(887674).call({from: address}, function(error, result){
console.log(result)
})
```